# What is the optimal setting for max_execution_time?

Tags: php, htaccess

I'm looking at improving our server performance, and noticed that the stock EE .htaccess file sets the [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) to 18000, which really seems like a typo. 18000 seconds is *5 hours*. Should this be 1800?

Comment: I think sometimes you need 5 hours for the indexing. But not for the frontend. (hopefully...)

Comment: It depends on so many factors. PHP execution should not exceed 600 (seconds), in general. A production server setting of 150 - 300 is ideal, but that depends on the setup and (especially) 3rd party modules. In any case, would this setting really offer performance increases?

Comment: Per the Apache documentation: 'This helps prevent poorly written scripts from tying up the server' - if the server allocates memory to php and then doesn't get it back for 5 hours, seems like that might trigger some unwanted behavior...